# Twitter Application Token Expires

Tags: twitter, token, twitter-oauth

I am connecting to twitter application and fetching the oauth token values and storing in database. I have found that the token values expires and each time I logs in with twitter i get a new token values.

I am searching for offline_access which is provided by facebook.

Please help me out, if anyone has faced the same issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your application only accessing a single Twitter account, or does your app have to access multiple accounts?

Comment: I can confirm that Twitter's Access keys are expiring after logging out... I'm referring to the key they generate for you when you go to their developer pages and click on the app you've registered with them. This is thoroughly annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Are you storing the Token Key and Secret or Access Key and Secret? The Token key is temporary and should not need to be stored in a database. It is used once to get a permanent Access Key and Access Secret.

See [this](http://dret.net/lectures/mobapp-spring10/img/oauth-diagram.png) link for the full OAuth flow.
See [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) link for the OAuth RFC.

Comment: sorry Stephen, by Token i mean Access Key only, the Access Key is getting expired i.e I get new access key each time i logs in

Comment: The Access Key shouldn't expire unless the user revokes access via the Twitter Apps page. With OAuth you don't 'log on', once you have an Access Key and Secret you just use them to access data. You should need to request new ones.

Comment: That should say "you shouldn't need to request new ones"

Comment: @AmolAress Twitter tokens do not ever expire unless the user revokes permission. use the permanent credentials given to you by twitter on ***the second token/secret request*** that you perform

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, upvote for you. While you can have a never ending access token with Facebook API:

> If your app needs an access token with an infinite expiry time
>   (perhaps to take actions on the user's behalf after they are not using
>   your app), you can request the offline_access permission.

seems you can't have an infinite access token with Twitter. I think the answer would be move to [PIN-based authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization).